# Is there any way i can make stiky bar in ionic framework

Tags: html, ios, angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-bootstrap

is there any way i can make stiky bar in ionic i have implemented but the problem is in ios buts are vibrating in ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt42Y.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the css property `position: fixed`? (its widely [accepted](https://caniuse.com/css-fixed)), with a combination with `top` and probably a `width` and `height` should be enough

```
position: fixed;
top: 94%;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: red;
```

Comment: i dont want fixed and i want stiky untill scroll reaches to end it should be fixed and then it should not fixed it should scroll with content

Comment: Can you elaborate in what you want to accomplish?, or attach something that can help visualize it. Do you want it to be fixed only for a moment?

Comment: u can see above screenshot add to wish list and add cart should be fixed untill treanding on visible after that it should be relative it is working perfectly fine in android in ios its shaking or vibrating when i scroll down

Comment: Please share in your question the code you are using. Or -if you can- share a code-sandbox or a repo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683025/position-sticky-is-working-fine-but-there-is-little-bit-vibrationdancing-when/70683302#70683302

check this link once