# position sticky is working fine but there is little bit vibration(dancing) when user scrolling in ionic app ? how can we avoid this in ios?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, ionic-framework, sass

can any suggest for this issue
position sticky is working fine but there is little bit vibration/dancing when user scrolling in ionic app ? how can we avoid this in ios?

```
<ion-item-divider sticky="true">
     <ion-label>
      Basic Item Divider
     </ion-label>
 </ion-item-divider>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `overflow-scroll=true` and then making the position sticky in the css. I have had problems with making ionic content use the sticky position within the tag itself.

Comment: This is not working please let me know if u can suggest other option thank u